# Can you use grepl with row values?

Tags: r, regex, grepl

I'm trying to see if a dataframe of usernames contains full names from another dataframe.

I'm iterating over each username and using *grepl* to see if the username contains the first name and last name from a different dataframe.

I've tried:

```
    matches <- 0
    for (i in df1$usernames)
    {
      if (grepl(df2$FIRST_NAME, i, fixed=TRUE) & grepl(df2$LAST_NAME, i, fixed=TRUE))
      {
         matches <- matches+1
      }
     }
```

Is it possible to use grepl for values in a column, instead of string? Because it isn't working - if not, how else can I see if the first name and last name of a row are in a username.

E.g. `John123Doe, JohnDoe123, JohnDoe` should all match with a row containing `"John"` and `"Doe"`

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```r
df1 <- data.frame(username=c("John123Doe", "JohnDoe123", "JohnDoe", "JonDoe", "YonDo"))
df2 <- data.frame(First=c("Jack","Joe", "Jon", "John", "Jo"), 
                  Last=c("Doe", "Dohe", "Doer", "Doe", "Do"))

findUser <- function(x) {
  res <- apply(df2, 1, function(y) grepl(y["First"], x) & grepl(y["Last"], x))
  ifelse(sum(res) > 0, paste(do.call("paste", df2[res,]), collapse=", "), NA)
}

df1$containsUserName <- sapply(df1$username, findUser)

df1
#>     username containsUserName
#> 1 John123Doe  John Doe, Jo Do
#> 2 JohnDoe123  John Doe, Jo Do
#> 3    JohnDoe  John Doe, Jo Do
#> 4     JonDoe            Jo Do
#> 5      YonDo             <NA>

# or vectorize the function:
FindUser <- Vectorize(findUser)
FindUser(df1$username)
#>        John123Doe        JohnDoe123           JohnDoe            JonDoe 
#> "John Doe, Jo Do" "John Doe, Jo Do" "John Doe, Jo Do"           "Jo Do" 
#>             YonDo 
#>                NA
```

<sup>Created on 2020-08-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: when I do that I get:
        Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, containsUserName, value = list()) : replacement has 0 rows, data has 22873

Comment: Is that using the example above (which *should* be reproducible), or your own data structures? It sounds like your df1 has no column named username.